# Comparison of experimental running time of algorithm vs. theoretical running time functions

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm writing simple algorithm for comparing if two vectors a1 and a2 of integers are anagrams (they contain the same elements in different orders). For example {2,3,1} and {3,2,1} are anagrams, {1,2,2} and {2,1,1} are not.

Here is my algorithm (it's very simple):

```
1. for ( i = 1; i <= a1.length; i++ )
 1.1. j = i
 1.2. while ( a1[i] != a2[j] )
  1.2.1. if ( j >= a1.length )
   1.2.1.1. return false
  1.2.2. j++
 1.3. tmp = a2[j]
 1.4. a2[j] = a2[i]
 1.5. a2[i] = tmp
2. return true
```

Representation of comparing two anagrams:
[image]

Lets consider function of running time dependent on vector sizes T(n) when they are anagrams in two situations: pesimistic and average.

- pessimistic

Occurs when vectors doesn't have duplicate elements and vectors are in reverse orders.

[image]

Multiplicity in c3, c4 and c6 are:

[image]

So the final function for pesimistic running time is:
[image]

Equation (3) can be written in a simpler form:
[image]

- average

Occurs when vectors doesn't have duplicate elements and vectors are in random orders. Critical assumption here is that: on average we find corresponding element from a1 in half of not sorted a2 (j/2 in c3, c4 and c6).

[image]

Multiplicity in c3, c4 and c6 are:
[image]

Final function for average running time is:
[image]

Written in simpler form:
[image]

---

**Here is my final conclusion and question:**

b2 in equation (8) is two times smaller than a2 in equation (4)
[image]

Am I right with (9)?

I thought that plotting running time of algorithm in function of vector sizes can proof equation (9) but it's not:
[image]

On the plot we can see that ratio a2/b2 is 1.11, not like in equation (9) where is 2. Ratio in above plot is far away from predicted. 
Why is that?

Comment: @StackFlowed It appears to be a question as-is. A pretty well written one.

Comment: @Everettss I think your problem is your assumption: "on average we find corresponding element from a1 in half of not sorted a2." Where does this assumption come from?

Comment: @mebob I made this assumption based on very similar problem in well known book Introduction to algorithms / Thomas H. Cormen http://www.ime.usp.br/~geiser/courses/MAC5711%20-%20An%C3%A1lise%20de%20Algoritmos/Introduction%20to%20Algorithms%20(Instructor's%20Manual).pdf You can find it on page 11 and the same assumption on 18 page: "⇒ On average, the while loop has to look halfway through the sorted subarray
A[1 . . j − 1] to decide where to drop key.
⇒ tj = j/2."
I also measure this experimentally. It is in half way. 
I didn't mention that: I measure each point on plot 100 times.

Comment: They used that assumption for finding the correct place to place a random element into the sorted subarray in insertion sort. I'm not exactly sure how that applies to your situation, as you are looking through an unsorted array.

Comment: @mebob I wasn't also convinced at the beginningto this assumption: j/2. But I measure it and it is true. I measure it on average for 100 repeats (the same like for points on plot).

Comment: I just noticed two problems with your analysis: 1. you sum from 1 to n in the inner loop, when you should be summing from i to n, and 2. you sum j/2 from 1 to n when you should be summing j from 1 to (n-i)/2. You forgot to take into account the shrinking of the unvisited side of a2, and you incorrectly calculated the multiplicity for iterating over half of the range (instead you calculated cost of iterating over the WHOLE range, then divided by two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found my problem!**

It wasn't as I thought in assumption for average case: "we find corresponding element from a1 in half of not sorted a2 (j/2)". It was hidden in pessimistic case.

**Proper pessimistic scenario occurs when vector a2 is in the same order as a1 with shifted first element to the end.** For example:

a1 = {1,2,3,4,5}

a2 = {2,3,4,5,1}

I measured experimentally once again running time of my algorithm with new assumption for pessimistic case. Here are results:

[image]

Finally experimental ratio for **a2/b2 is: 2.03 +/- 0.09**

And it's proof for my theoretical functions.

Thank for all of you for being with me and trying to solve my trivial mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that the same instructions in the two cases will take same amount of time.
In particular, in your pessimistic case, the branches will always go the same way, hence branch predictors will do a great job and you won't pay the penalty of mis-prediction (which can be quite high).

In case of random order, the branches will be harder to predict and so your branch instructions will take much longer to execute. This could easily explain the difference you are see

Comment: For all measurements I repeated it 100 times. And all values which you can se on plots are averages. So I can measure and predict it on average.

Comment: Everettss, my comment was not about your ability to predict run-time, but the microprocessor's ability to predict which way a branch (if condiion,for example) will go. This has very significant impact on how fast a program can run. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor